# Is it possible to set the Google Map key dynamically?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to pass the key through url to iframe from parent window.
After fetching the data from URL I want to set it in the map `src`.
Is this possible?

Because it's working fine when I'm using this code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=4">
</script>

<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

But if I try this way I'm not sure whether it's using the key or not. Without key also google map works.
I have put one `console.log` statement but it's not printing anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
mapKey="45"
</script>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+mapKey>
console.log(mapKey)
</script>

<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript will not be parsed in HTML-attributes, create the script dynamically.

Example retrieving the key from the `location.hash`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(key){
  var url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initialize',
      script=document.createElement('script');
  if(key)url+='&key='+key;
  script.setAttribute('src',url);
  //load the API
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
}(
  //get the key from the URL
  location.hash.substr(1)
  ));
</script>
```

**Note:** remove this line

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

....the API will run `initialize` automatically

sample-iframe:

```
  <iframe src="iframe.htm#yourmapsapikey"></iframe>
```

Comment: So you are saying my iframe should be like this-
`<iframe src="iframe.html#map_key?arg1&arg2"></iframe>`
And html code will start from your script then I should put the `initialize` function?
Can you please give a demo?

Comment: the hash must be the last in the URL, so when you want to add GET-parameters the iframe-URL must be: `iframe.html?arg1&arg2#map_key`